# Access sails locals from view

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm playing around with Sails.js and trying to do some basic stuff to figure out how it works. I need to pass a variable to my view from the controller, should be simple. The routing works, but the variable isn't there, what am I missing ?

Controller

```
  index: function (req, res) {

  User.find().exec(function list(err, listed){
    return res.view('user/index', {users: listed});
  });
}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    <% _.each(users, function (dawg) { %>
    <li><%= dawg.name %></li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: /home/ejerhar/git/swriter/views/user/index.ejs:2
    1| <ul>
 >> 2|     <% _.each(users, function (dawg) { %>
    3|     <li><%= dawg.name %></li>
    4|     <% }) %>
    5| </ul>

users is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical, as soon as I post a question I find the answer.

The problem was a GET route I had specified to the view, the routes override the controller